# Vector array erase not working

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, erase

My vector.erase() function gives me an error -> "error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'Fire'

here is the code and the vector is declared in the header file.

any help is appreciated.

```
//header
std::vector<Fire> _fires;

//cpp
void Fire::update()
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < _fires.size(); i++)
    {

    _fires[i].lifeTimer(); // updates the lifetime for all objects

        if (_fires[i]._lifetime >= 200)
        {
            _fires.erase(_fires.begin() + i); //erase not working
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You kind of forgot to ask a question. What don't you understand about this? The error message seems to completely explain the issue.

Comment: I hope `Fire::update()` is a static member function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your basic problem is that you have tried to design a single class which does two different things:

- Contains a vector of fires
- Implements the behaviour of a fire

A much better design is to have two separate classes

1  A class to implement the behaviour of a fire

2  A class which contains a vector of fires, and implements methods, such as update, to iterate over the fires contained in the vector, invoking the fire methods.

It would look like this:

```
class Fire {
  // implements individual method on an instance of fire, such as  liefetime
};

class FireContainer {
  // implements method to deal with all the fires, such as update
  std:: vector< Fire > myFires;

};
```

However, if you want to continue with a single class, and have the vector of fires as global ( usually considered bad practice ) then the method update should not be a member of the Fire class, but a free function.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

I followed your suggestion and made a separate class for the vector array, it somewhat fixed it but i ended up with another problem. Now when the fires are deleted a white rectangle appears on another fire for a second or two. I'm not sure but i'm guessing it's because the array needs to fill in the empty spot.

Comment: nvm i fixed by setting the texture for all the fires after one i destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Fire` class doesn't have an assignment operator, or it is not accessible.

But the `vector::erase()` implementation must need it because, as http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/ points out, erasing elements might cause elements to be relocated.